# How can I install qt quick 2 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, qt5, qtquick2

I'm getting acquainted with qt5 and I use Ubuntu 12.04. I managed to install qt5 and some libs, but I can't figure out how to install new QtQuick. I'm using “Canonical Qt5 Edgers” ppa.

Answer (score 3):

I, too, had the "QtQuick 2.0 is not installed" error.  Everything I found online referenced installing Qt5 correctly or certain subdirectories as solutions.  But I found, even though I followed the instructions that I saw online to install through the command line (apt-get), that I was missing **qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin** so I grabbed that (and a few other plugins) from the package manager and immediately the tutorial I was attempting finally executed.  So you might want to check that you have that plugin, first.

Comment: Could you post a link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 I just executed the .run installer from the [Qt Project downloads page](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

Though, you may run into some minor file permission issues if you choose to run the installer with root permissions. In particular, if you run the installer with sudo, don't have it run Qt Creator when installation is finished. Uncheck the option, close the wizard, and start Qt Creator yourself.